# Is there a program that can display the bitmap corresponding to a specified GDI handle?

Tags: gdi

I'm trying to use GDIView to trace a GDI object leak in my code, but although it gives the dimensions of bitmap objects, it would be useful to see the actual image itself.  How can I display the bitmap corresponding to a given handle and/or kernel address (both are displayed by GDIView)?